# Azure easy table connection string missing

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile app created, and am about to setup Easy Table. I have followed each step and have created a connection string to a SQL database created before the mobile app. But when I initialized app to use Easy Table, I got the error message which is: "Missing SQL Server connection string". But I have already added a connection string before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue and tried many times and it failed each time. Until my last try which went ok. The only difference with before? Well, I kept the default connection string name whereas before I was customizing it...

Comment: Ok, that really works. This bug is really annoying. Hope Microsoft fix it soon.

Comment: This is absolutely incredible! Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Leave the default connection string name "MS_TableConnectionString" and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you select the free DB plan. Select the basic instead; it will work. I don't have an explanation for that but it works for me.